# Sealed class and Singleton

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static, singleton

I am looking at [Jon Skeet's implementation of Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

I have few questions on this:

1. Why the class is sealed?
2. What if I do not want it sealed? Is it going to break my Singleton implementations?
3. One of the major reason I am going for Singleton as oppose to a a static is because I want my class to be open for in inheritance. If eventually, I am going to make it sealed and make it devoid of any kind of inheritance then why not static?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If it's not sealed then someone can create derived types of it, create instances of those types, and then all of a sudden you have more than one instance of your "singleton".
2. It's going to allow for people to potentially create additional instances.  If you either don't care if they do, and/or know that nobody is going to be bothered to try, then you certainly can unseal the class.  Of course, the only reason to make the class explicitly *not* sealed would be to create derived types, which would almost certainly necessitate creating multiple instances of the type.  This means that you almost certainly no longer have a singleton.  Of course, having a not-actually-singleton type may be appropriate in your situation, in which case, go right ahead.
3. If you make it static then you can't create the *one* instance that you want to make it a singleton; you can only ever have *zero*.

Comment: `If it's not sealed then someone can create derived types of it, create instances of those types...` But if the singleton has a single private constructor the derived class wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Shoe [Nope](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/10/23/violating-the-smart-enum-pattern-in-c/).  It's possible.  Evil, but possible.  Blame Jon Skeet for opening Pandora's Box on that one.